# ¿Error Esperaba un parametro C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo un método que recibe un parametro y devuelve una lista de datos, pero me generar diciendo que esperaba un parametro.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function 'sp_List_TaRuma_Desc' expects parameter '@desc', which was not supplied.'
```

Aquí esta mi método

```
public List<Ruma> listaRumaxDesc(string parametro)
        {
            var rumas = new List<Ruma>();
            using (cn = objCon.getConexion())
            {
                cn.Open();
                var query = new SqlCommand("sp_List_TaRuma_Desc", cn);
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", parametro);

                using (var dr = query.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        var objRuma = new Ruma
                        {
                            codRuma = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Codruma"].ToString()),
                            nomRuma = dr["nomruma"].ToString()
                        };
                        rumas.Add(objRuma);
                    }
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
            return rumas;
        }
```

Pero cuando empiezo a debuggear si recibe la variable parametro.

Comment: Quien ejecuta esta funcion? si funciona en debug quiere decir que ese parametro se llena de alguna forma asincronicamente...

Comment: Lo que digo es que sí esta recibiendo el parámetro

Comment: Ah ok... comprendido.. entonces yo ni idea..

Comment: no te entiendo `expects parameter '@desc', which was not supplied.'` ¿y dices que sí le das un parámetro? ¿Seguro?

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta especificar el tipo de comando [`CommandType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_CommandType). 
Cuando se crea la clase [SqlCommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8#constructors) con el constructor `SqlCommand(String, SqlConnection)` 
 
El tipo de comando por defecto es [texto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype?view=netframework-4.8#property-value).

```
var query = new SqlCommand("sp_List_TaRuma_Desc", cn);
query.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", parametro);
```

En caso de que quieras utilizar el *stored procedure* en un SqlCommand de tipo texto tienes que escribirlo todo completo.

```
var query = new SqlCommand("EXEC sp_List_TaRuma_Desc @desc", cn);
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", parametro);
```